# How to approach this limit?$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{p=n}^ {kn}f \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let a real function defined on an open bounded neighbourhood of zero. Knowing that $f(0)=0$ and that f is differentiable at the origin, find the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{p=n}^ {kn}f \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$
$\text{I tried to use the differentiability from the hypothesis i.e }$
$$\lambda=f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x},$$ following that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $n_\epsilon$ such that for each $n \ge n_\epsilon, $ we have $\left(\lambda-\epsilon\right)\cdot x\le f(x)\le\left(\lambda+\epsilon\right) \cdot x$ Putting $x=\frac{1}{p},$ for $p=n,...., kn$ adding all the relations and making $\epsilon$ goes to zero, we will obtain that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{p=n}^ {kn}f \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)=\lambda\cdot \ln(k) $$
apologies for the lack of details of the proof but that is just a sketch waiting for its own validation to carry on with

Comment: i have changed that

Comment: Your result looks correct to me. Can you explain what your doubts are, or what exactly you want to know?

Comment: i wondered about the approach whether is right or not.The given solution from the book is laborious and that s the source of doubt, i wonder if there s a nonelementary way to do it

Comment: It is correct, but you omitted some steps. At present I find it difficult to know what exactly you are asking for. If you want to compare your solution with the one from the textbook then you should show that also.

Comment: Your approach is right. You can present it at a “higher level” (without $\epsilon$) as follows: since $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=\lambda$, one has $$f\!\left(\frac1p\right)\sim\frac\lambda p$$
as $p\to\infty$. Now $\Sigma\frac1p$ is a diverging series, so for every integer $k\ge1$, $$\sum_{p=n}^{kn}f\!\left(\frac1p\right)\sim\lambda\sum_{p=n}^{kn}\frac1p,$$
as $n\to\infty$. [Using that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $\sum_{p=1}^n\frac1p=\ln n+\gamma+o(1),$ we have
$$\sum_{p=n}^{kn}\frac1p\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ln(k),$$
and we can conclude.

Comment: One way to prove the last bit of your argument is to notice that $$\sum^{nk}_{p=n}\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k-1}{(k-1)n}\sum^{(k-1)n}_{j=1}\frac{1}{1+\tfrac{k-1}{n(k-1)}j}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^k_1\frac{dx}{x}=\log(k)$$
for the sum in the middle is the Riemann sum corresponding to the uniform partition with $(k-1)n$ pieces and right-end points tags of the integral  of $x\mapsto \frac1x$ over the interval $[1,k]$

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I will try to post the solution from the author today.